# Call web service from ajax (jquery) inside a for loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I would like to know what is the best way to go in order to call a web service using the $.ajax (jquery) method, considering that I need to call that web service multiple times and each time pass a different argument to it.
What I've tried so far:

1. Enclose the ajax call inside a **for** loop, but of course that
   didn't work (one ajax call did not end properly before instantiating
   the next one - and that's when I remembered that the first 'a' in
   ajax stands for ***asynchronous***).
2. Use the $.each method (similar
   result as above).
3. I thought about calling the web service
   recursively in the success callback option of the ajax call, passing
   one argument in each loop. Haven't gotten to this yet as I am not at
   my work's computer right now, but I was wondering whether there was
   a more elegant and faster way to approach the problem.

Any other ideas will be more than welcome. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

- FYI, the web service is used to insert data into a MS SQL DB.
- The numbers of arguments may vary (I mean it's not a fixed number).

Comment: do you own the webservice? then you should modify it to send all the different arguments in a batch and get a batch response from the service.

Comment: @MoXplod how do I send all the arguments at the same time in a batch? FYI, The expected response from the web service is insertion of data into a MS SQL DB.

Comment: Cant's this be done using arrays? I mean passing an array of the data you need as a parameter, and after that make a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic ways to do this:

1. Use promises to chain multiple ajax calls together.  The chaining process will force sequential operation so one finishes and then the next one launches.
2. In the success handler of the ajax call, launch the next ajax call (your third option).

If the different ajax calls do not actually depend upon one another, you can also launch them all in parallel and then serialize just the results.  This results in much faster end-to-end time.

Or, as others have suggested, if you can modify your web service so that multiple requests can be passed in one ajax call, then you can request all the data with one ajax call and the server will return all the data at once.

---

For the first option, here's an example of serializing ajax calls using promises:

[Sequential function calls in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451163/sequential-function-calls-in-javascript/23453978#23453978)

```
// serialize all requests
function A() {
    var p = $.get(url).then(function(data) {return $.post(url)});
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        // chain four more pairs of requests onto the original promise
        p = p.then(function() {return $.get(url)})
             .then(function(data) {return $.post(url)});
    }
    // return the promise so callers can monitor when A() is done
    return p;
}


function B() {
    // sequence these three operations one after the other
    return ($.get(url)
       .then(function(data) {return $.post(url + x)})
       .then(update_dropdown)
    );
}

// run them both, one after the other
A().then(B);
```

---

For the second option, you can't use a `for` loop because (as you've already figured out, it just launches all the ajax calls at once).  Instead, you restructure the looping so you launch the next iteration from the success handler.  Here's an example of the second option taken from some other code I have lying around:

```
(function() {

    var checked = $('.check_box_ping:checked');
    var index = 0;

    function next() {
        if (index < checked.length ) {
            var item = checked.eq(index++);
            // use item here for your post
            $.post({...}, function(response) {
                // do your normal handling of the response here
                ...
                // now kick off the next iteration of the loop
                next();
            });
        }
    }
    next();

})();
```

Here are a couple other examples:

[behavior of ajax call inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825932/behavior-of-ajax-call-inside-a-for-loop/22826096#22826096)

[Wait for AJAX to finish before proceeding with the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211631/wait-for-ajax-to-finish-before-proceeding-with-the-loop/23211681#23211681)

[While loop with jQuery async AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332049/while-loop-with-jquery-async-ajax-calls/19332078#19332078)

Comment: thank you so very much for such a thorough explanation! I will give it a try tomorrow first thing in the morning and get back to you to let you know how it went :).

Comment: I tried the solution you provided in the second link above and it worked like a charm. Thanks again for your time and for sharing your knowledge. Have a great day!